# Hive Query with a large WHERE Condition

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am writing a HIVE query to pull about 2,000 unique keys from a table.

I keep getting this error - java.lang.StackOverflowError

My query is basic but looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (Id = 1 or Id = 2 or Id = 3 Id = 4)
```

my WHERE clause goes all the way up to 2000 unique id's and I receive the error above.   Does anyone know of a more efficient way to do this or get this query to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any chance you can put all the id's in a list, and join them

Comment: You can put the unque keys in another table then; SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in (select keys from uniq_id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `SPLIT` and `EXPLODE` to convert the comma separated string to rows and then use `IN` or `EXISTS`.

using `IN`

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable t WHERE
  t.ID IN
( 
 SELECT 
    explode(split('1,2,3,4,5,6,1998,1999,2000',',')) as id
)  ;
```

Using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable t WHERE
  EXISTS 
  ( 
   SELECT 1 FROM ( 
      SELECT 
        explode(split('1,2,3,4,5,6,1998,1999,2000',',')) as id
  ) s 

  WHERE s.id = t.id 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the Between clause instead of specifying all unique ids:

```
SELECT ID FROM table WHERE ID BETWEEN 1 AND 2000 GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: The ID's are not actually in order.  They are all over the place - like 123kdinwo2, 234ksikj3, etc... So I am not sure that wold work

Answer (score 0):

i you can create a table for these IDs and after use the condition of exist in the new table to get only your specific IDs